# The case of Young's inequality for convolution for $1\leq p\leq 2$ implies the case $p\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm doing an exercise asking us to show that if for $ 1\leq p\leq 2$, the inequality for convolution $||f*g||_p\leq ||f||_1 ||g||_p$ holds, then it holds for $p\geq 2$.

The exercise suggests using Theorem 15.9 [Bass] which is the following:

> For $1<p<\infty$, and $1/p+1/q=1$, suppose $f\in L^p$. Then
> $ ||f||_p =\operatorname{sup} \{ \int fgd\mu:||g||_q\leq 1\}.$

Suppose $p\geq 2$, take $h= f*g/(||f||_1||g||_q)$. Then $||h||_q\leq 1$ and $\int (f*g )h d\mu\leq ||f*g||_p$. If  using Minkovski's inequality to get $\int (f*g )h d\mu\leq ||f*g||_p||f*g||_q/(||f||_1||g||_q)$, I'm thinking if there is a function
$h$ that makes the equality holds so that I can conclude the result. I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Can someone suggest how to solve this problem please?

The following is the full description.

> [image]

Comment: You're only testing one particular $h$, but $\| f*g \|_p$ is a supremum (as in Theorem 15.9 of the reference) over $h$ such that $\|h\|_q \leq 1$.

Comment: @mathdoge Can you please suggest how to test other $h$?

Comment: Have you learned Minkowski's inequality for integrals? Indeed all the cases for $1 \leq p < \infty$ is an (almost) immediate consequence of it, and $p = \infty$ is just Holder's inequality. I am thinking about how to use the duality result (Thm 15.9 you mentioned).

Comment: Yes this result can be proved at once for all $1\leq p< \infty $ but the question asks us to deduce the case $p\geq 2$ from the case $1\leq p\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: If $f,g,h \in C_c(\Bbb R^n),$ then by Fubini's theorem we have
$$ \int_{\Bbb R^n} (f \ast g)(x) h(x) \,\mathrm{d} x = \int_{\Bbb R^n} \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(y) g(x-y) h(x) \,\mathrm{d} y \,\mathrm{d} x = \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(y) (g \ast h)(y) \,\mathrm{d}y. $$
Using this you can establish the inequality
$$ \left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}(f \ast g)(x) h(x) \,\mathrm{d} x \right| \leq \lVert f \rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_1 \lVert h \rVert_{p'}. $$
Can you take it form here?